# Why does *::selection not give you the correct colour?

Tags: css, background, selection

I have Googled this but can't find any info on it.

Say you set your page highlight colour to a nice **orange**:

```
*::selection {
     background: #C44610;
 }
```

Why, when you highlight your page, does the background show as **red**, I swabbed this colour in photoshop and it gives me a hex value of #c24432 which is way off the orange I selected.

I have tested this on Chrome. In firefox I can't get the selection to work at all, it just gives me the default colour.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

For example you can edit this code:

```
::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
```

Comment: Using the above code will give you the global ::selection style you desire.

Comment: Prefixes start and end with a dash ( - ) and I don't think the -webkit- vendor prefix is necessary

Answer (score 1):

Don't need the *

Also will need the `::-moz-selection {}` for Firefox

BTW, you shoulkd consider that since the selection color is a bit transparent, it changes depending on the background...

Greetings from Argentina

Comment: Interesting, I didn't actually think about the transparency issue. Since there's no way around this, do you have any ideas on finding the correct hex that you match my initial orange?

Comment: Since it depends on the background, it's actually imposible. Hence you find the correct color over white, it won't be the same if the background is black, for instance.